# How can I center the second row vertically in an up-and-down carousel using Tailwind CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm working on creating an up-and-down carousel using Tailwind CSS, and I'm facing an issue with centering the elements in the second row of my grid. My goal is to have the elements in the second row vertically centered within the grid.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry2sz.png)

```
const Carousel = () => {
  return (
    <div className='grid grid-cols-2 gap-12 '>
        <div className='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'>

        </div>
        <div className='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'>

        </div>
        <div className='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'>

        </div>
        <div className='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'>

        </div>
        <div className='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'>

        </div>
        <div className='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'>

        </div>
        <div className='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'>

        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default Carousel;
```

I am expecting a result similar this is below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkP7F.png)

Comment: Instead of going for a grid i'd just use flex and have `self-right` class on the even divs.  If you want them a bit overlap you can play around with negative margins using `-my-x` make sure all your elements have a display block so they each take a row in your layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do would require changing the approach of your layout a bit. Because of the way the grid works, an equal number of blocks on the x and y axis will be created. Even if the last item is not filled, the space would be allocated (virtually, if that makes sense).

So I altered your code a bit to achieve the same thing you are trying to do. Maybe it fits your use-case, but yes it does exactly what you want, using `flex`.

See Result on [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2Cid93r1jQ).

```
<div class='grid grid-cols-2 gap-12 justify-center'>
    <div class='flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-full gap-12'>
        <div class='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'></div>
        <div class='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'></div>
        <div class='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'></div>
        <div class='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-full gap-12'>
        <div class='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'></div>
        <div class='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'></div>
        <div class='w-72 h-48 bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```